# a python class for modular integers that supports addition and negation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to come up with code for the definition addition and negation in python. The most similar thing I have is for multiplication, which I've copied below. Any ideas on what should be changed to account for addition and negation of modular integers? I know subtraction is just the addition of negation in this problem. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
class Zp:

    p = 2 #class attribute

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n % Zp.p #instance attribute

    def __str__(self):
        #msg = '[' + str(self.n) + ']'
        msg = str(self.n) + ' mod ' + str(Zp.p) + ')'
        return msg

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    # def __add__(self, other):
        # [a], [b] in Zp ([a], [b] are sets of integers)
        # [a]+[b] = [a+b] e.g. a+b mod p
    # def __neg__(self, other):
    # def __sub__ (self, other): # the addition of negation

    def __mul__(self, other): # [a]*[b] = [a*b] e.g. a*b mod p
        if Zp.__instancecheck__(other):
            return Zp(self.n * other.n)
        elif type(other) == int:
            return Zp(self.n * other)
        else:
            raise TypeError('multiplication a Zp with a non-Zp or non-integer')
```

what I have tried for addition:

```
def __add__(self, other): # [a]*[b] = [a*b] e.g. a*b mod p
        if Zp.__instancecheck__(other):
            return Zp(self.n + other.n)
        elif type(other) == int:
            return Zp(self.n + other)
```

Comment: You say you're trying, what have you tried? The code provided only shows the basic solution for multiplication - the answer is pretty straightforward, this seems like a "getting SO to do my homework" question, but perhaps you can elaborate on the trouble you're having.

Comment: A few things that can be improved in your `__mul__` code: You should probably use `isinstance` for your type checking, rather than the other methods you have now. And when you give up, you should return `NotImplemented` rather than explicitly raising an error (Python will do that for you, if the other object doesn't have a suitable reversed operator method, e.g. `__radd__`, that works with your class). Speaking of reversed operators, you might want them yourself, so that `1 + Zp(1)` works as well as `Zp(1) + 1`.

Comment: @emitsch: Please [edit] your additional code into the question, rather than posting it in a comment where it can't be formatted properly.

Comment: Thank you Blackknght! And I should be using 'NotImplemented' instead of raising the TyperError?

Comment: @emitsch: Probably yes, but it's not super important. It lets other types work with your class, even if you don't know about them ahead of time. You can read more about the `NotImplemented` constant [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented).

Comment: Your code for the addition looks fine, you just need to deal with cases like `Zp(2) + "12"` - i.e. what if `other` is neither a `Zp` nor an `int`? The solution is the same as for `mul`. You should be able to use the exact same pattern for `sub` and `neg` (although `neg` is a lot simpler, no `other`)

Answer (score 0):

When doing modular arithmetic on numbers, you can generally do the normal operation (adding, subtracting, multiplying), then take the answer mod your modulus.

For example,

> 3 * 3 mod 2 = 9 mod 2 = 1 mod 2

In order to implement the operations you're specifying, do the operation, then take the modulo. Take a look at Wikipedia's article for more information about how to do modular arithmetic: [Modular Arithmetic - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: There's no bug in the existing `__mul__` implementation (not in terms of computing the value anyway). The modulus happens in the call to `Zp`, in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Right. Missed that.